# QGIS2WEB Plugin (openLayer3) for QGIS not exporting raster images

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis2web

I am using the QGIS2WEB plugin for QGIS. I have added vector features as well as a raster image (.tif or .ecw) format.

When I try to export the webmap, all the layers are visible expect the rasters. Why is this?

Comment: Can you try the same with the plugin "Export to OpenLayers 3"? qgis2web uses that plugin's code to export to OL3.

Comment: Hi Tom, I have tried that, but to no avail. None of the the web mapping plugins display my raster layer at all.

Comment: Can you make the raster available to everyone by uploading it somewhere? I should say that raster support is not as fully featured as vector. It would be good to improve it, and this particular problem could kickstart it. Edit: this should have been a comment. Misled by Android app. Apologies.

Comment: Hi Tom, here is the download link for the raster. It is in .ecw format, but i have converted it to .tif and .jpeg, but none of these solutions worked. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B37-vtUDnWlYaVpmeXNhWUYzSlE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having some trouble and reducing the image size helped. What I did was:
1. Set the image colors the way you want (pallet, histogram stretch etc)
2. Export the image using the "Save as..." option when you right click
3. Change the output mode of the saved image to 'Rendered image'. That will create a 3 band, 8 bit image. I also clipped the image extent to make it smaller

Reducing the image size helps because the qgis2web plugin will convert your tif image to a png and that process can take some time

Comment: I've also just removed some failing code from the raster export in Leaflet. The code was an attempt to handle stylized rasters, but was not working. @Daniel's method should help.